# Reading Excel and insert or update the ListItem using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom, insert-update-listitem

I want to read an excel file that resides on the file system and insert/update the values into the SPList item programmatically. I tried with the CSOM approach, but am unable to get the desired output.
 here is my code:

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {            try            {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext clientContextproj = 
        new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("");
            Web siteproj = clientContextproj.Web;
            // clientContextproj.AuthenticationMode = 
             //ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            // clientContextproj.Credentials = new 
         //System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", 
              //"domain");
            CamlQuery query1 = new CamlQuery();
            query1.ViewXml = "<View><Query><FieldRef Name='Country'/>
             <Value Type='Text'></Value></Query></View>";

            List resourceMaster = siteproj.Lists.GetByTitle("Test1");
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = 
           resourceMaster.GetItems(query1);
            clientContextproj.Load(items);
            clientContextproj.ExecuteQuery();
            Excel.Application ap = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook wb = 
          ap.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\sa06\\Desktop\\Report.xlsx");
            Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.ActiveSheet;
            bool flag = true;
            int counter = 2;
            while (flag)
            {
                string columnHeader = "A" + counter.ToString();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row = 
               ws.get_Range(columnHeader);
                row.Value2 = row.Text.ToString().Trim();
                if (row.Value2 != null)
                {
                    if (items.Count != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(listItem["Country"]);
                            var currentResourceId = listItem["Country"];                            
                    if (currentResourceId != null && 
                   currentResourceId.Equals(row.Value2))
                            {
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range Exprow = 
                   ws.get_Range("B" + counter.ToString());
                                    string ValueTotal = 
                     Convert.ToString(Exprow.Value2);
                                    listItem["Region"] = ValueTotal;
                                    listItem.Update();
                                    clientContextproj.ExecuteQuery();                                       
                                    break;
                            }                              }
                        }                        }
                    else
                    {                            flag = false;       }
                }                 }

          catch (Exception ex) 
          {
            throw ex;
          }
      }
```

Do I need to make changes in the code anywhere? though it reads the excel file's 2nd column and update the corresponding listitems , it seems when the value is not matching with the listitem,it failes.

```
[![country-region-excel][1]][1]
```

Here as you can see in the excel file,am reading the Country column first and check the same in SPLIst item[compare] if the region in the SPListItem is not **IN** , I need to update the listitem as **IN**.

No, am not getting any error, but its not updating as expected.
Is my approach is wrong? I mean, I will first read the excel cell value of country column and region and compare/equals-check the same against the first record of SPList and if it equals then I will update the value else ignore.

Comment: What part is not working, do you get an error?

Comment: am not getting any error. Its not working as expected , not updating the value in splistitem.